# How to change Netbeans search results color

Tags: netbeans

I changed my Netbeans default theme to Dracula LaF,
I want to change results matching words because it's the same color for the whole sentence.

You can see my problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn1l5.jpg).

I search the word "global" and I want to change matching words color.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to specifically change the font color or background color for the search string within the results displayed in the **Search Results** window. Instead the search string is simply shown in bold in the same color as the font color. That doesn't work well at all for your **Darcula** theme, but for other themes with black font on a white background it is very clear.

However, even though there is no direct solution for your problem, there are still a couple of options that may or may not work for you.

One approach is to use a different dark theme instead of **Darcula** to see if the way the search results are rendered with that theme is more to your liking. There are many alternatives available. For example:

- You could try the **Dark Look and Feel Themes** plugin which is available for installation from **Tools -> Plugins**.
- [This site has 24 themes](https://netbeansthemes.com/).
- [This site has over 90 themes](http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/).

However, my experience is that the highlighting of light fonts does not stand out as well as the highlighting of dark fonts. Given that, an alternative approach is to continue using **Darcula** for code editing, but some other scheme for the rest of the NetBeans panels and windows.

To do that go to **Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Look and feel** and then make a selection from the **Preferred look and feel** drop list:

[image: AppearanceScreen]

I chose **Nimbus** which has a black font on a white background. Here's the NetBeans screen before the change, using only the **Darcula** theme:

[image: DarculaTheme]

And here's the same NetBeans screen after adding the **Nimbus** look and feel and restarting NetBeans:

[image]

Aesthetically the pure **Darcula** screen looks better, but as a practical matter those search strings in the **Search Results** window are far more visible when using **Nimbus**. If you spend most of your time in NetBeans with your code window expanded to full screen the change probably won't be relevant most of the time.

As a long term solution, one other thing you could do is raise a bug report with NetBeans requesting the ability to custom configure the **Search Results** window. They have already done that for the **Terminal** and **Output** windows (through **Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous** then selecting the **Output** or **Terminal** tab).